# By what principle may county courts in London be expected to follow certain past decisions?

Tags: england-and-wales, court, judge

"Now we have a county court appeal judgment on the issue, from HHJ Luba KC. Still not a binding precedent, but of persuasive value (and will be followed in the London courts). " https://nearlylegal.co.uk/2023/08/return-of-deposit-by-cheque-definitely-maybe

What is meant by this blog passage?

Answer (score 2):

County Court judges aren't obliged to follow the decisions made by County Court judges in prior cases with similar facts and issues.

However, assuming the County Court judge's decision isn't subject to binding precedent (from higher courts), she may base her decision on prior decisions, referring to them for '[persuasive precedent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precedent#Persuasive_precedent)' or 'persuasive authority' - useful or relevant material that guided the judge to make her decision.

HHJ Luba KC is a senior circuit judge and the designated civil judge at Central London County Court. After being called to the bar in 1980, he built a practice in social housing law. He has written several books and numerous articles about housing law. He is regarded as an expert, an authority, in housing law. As a judge he has heard many housing cases.